# Making composite focusable in SWT

Tags: java, user-interface, focus, swt, swt-awt

Is it possible to create a focusable composite in SWT? I'm catching all keyboard events via Display filter, but there are some problems when the focus is on the tree or list - GTK+'s default action is to search in the contents of the control.

What I want to do is to mix SWT and AWT with focusable AWT component. I managed to make the AWT widget unfocusable and I added Display filter to make the AWT component receiving keyboard events (but not directly), even when it's not focused. But there are several problems when some SWT controls are focused - that's why I want to make composite focusable.

So my final question is: is it possible to make SWT composite focusable?

Comment: It's not a duplicate... In linked topic above, the user wants to do something totally different... He wants to skip certain controls in Composite; I want to make composite keyboard-focusable. There's no need to close my question because I don't have any answer yet.

Comment: The point of that question is exactly the same - to tab-select the composite. I would recommend you trying the solution from that question reply.

Comment: No... I don't want to tab-select composite. I want to make composite keyboard-focusable; make the composite catching keyboard events by clicking on it (just like you do when you click, for example, text box); I repeat - I don't want to tab-select it. And I can't try the solution from that question reply, because I don't have any controls in my composite (or, to be exact, I have 1 AWT control in this SWT composite, but I don't want to make AWT control focusable because it causes a lot of glitches...).

Comment: "_I had to create new question because the previous one wasn't reopened_" Wrong. You don't **have** to do this. The old question wasn't reopened for a reason. Voted for close again.

Comment: @Baz what's the reason?

Comment: Ok, good luck with this attitude then...

Comment: If your question is closed, then at least 5 people or a moderator think it's best to close it. Your new question contains almost the same content (if not less) than your previous one. If this question will not be closed that's ok for me. As I said, I wish you all the best with your question.

Comment: Can you post some code? Which component do you try to wrap?

Answer (score 3):

If a `Composite` contains child widgets, the default action is to give up focus when it is selected.  To circumvent this, start by extending the `Composite` class as such:

```
class FocusableComposite extends Composite
{
    public FocusableComposite(Composite parent, int style)
    {
        super(parent, style);
    }

    public boolean setFocus()
    {
        return super.forceFocus();
    }
}
```

Then use a `MouseListener` on a new instantiation of FocusableComposite to call setFocus() directly whenever the `Composite` is clicked:

```
Composite composite = new FocusableComposite(shell, SWT.NONE);

composite.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
{
    public void mouseDown(MouseEvent event)
    {
        ((Composite)event.widget).setFocus();
    }
});
```