# Focusable composite - SWT

Tags: java, user-interface, focus, swt, swt-awt

Is it possible to create a focusable composite in SWT? I'm catching all keyboard events via Display filter, but there are some problems when the focus is on the tree or list - GTK+'s default action is to search in the contents of the control.

What I want to do is to mix SWT and AWT with focusable AWT component. I managed to make the AWT widget unfocusable and I added Display filter to make the AWT component receiving keyboard events (but not directly), even when it's not focused. But there are several problems when some SWT controls are focused - that's why I want to make composite focusable.

So my final question is: is it possible to make SWT composite?

By the way, this question is repost of: [Making composite focusable in SWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921614/making-composite-focusable-in-swt). Some people probably think that *this* topic is a duplicate: it isn't. Longer explanation is provided in the question that I linked. I had to create new question because the previous one wasn't reopened...

Comment: The reason is that people still think it's a duplicate. That's the reason why it was closed in the first place...

Comment: But it is NOT a duplicate... And I don't care what people thinks, they're wrong. By the way, Stack Overflow says: "If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different or __ask a new question__."

Comment: I wanted to get answer for my question. Instead of that, I received "that question is a duplicate" box, although it's not a duplicate. What else I can do? My previous question is not a duplicate; if it was a duplicate, I wouldn't explain that, I wouldn't vote for reopening and I wouldn't post second question. That's not a matter of my attitude.

Comment: I really didn't want to post new question. But I really didn't have any choice; my previous question was closed, as you say, by 5 people that thought it is a duplicate. At this moment there are 2 votes for reopening for 2 days. I explained why my question is not a duplicate after it was closed, and at this moment nothing says that it will be reopened soon (or anytime).